# DataGridTemplateColumn cell with Custom Control not displayed after updating

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, custom-controls, observablecollection

In my project, I have a custom control LessonCell.
Generic.xaml:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:LessonCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:LessonCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="LessonGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding SubjectName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding CabinetName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding TeacherName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

LessonCell.cs:

```
public class LessonCell : Control
{
    static LessonCell()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LessonCell),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LessonCell)));
    }

    public string TeacherName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TeacherNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TeacherNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TeacherNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TeacherName",
            typeof(string), typeof(LessonCell), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string SubjectName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SubjectNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SubjectNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubjectNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SubjectName",
            typeof(string), typeof(LessonCell), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string CabinetName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CabinetNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CabinetNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CabinetNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CabinetName",
            typeof(string), typeof(LessonCell), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

I use this control as a Datagrid cell. For this, when I generate the columns of a table, I set it as CellTemplate:

```
                DataGridTemplateColumn lessonColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
                lessonColumn.Header = (i + 1) + " урок";
                FrameworkElementFactory lessonCell = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(LessonCell));
                lessonCell.SetBinding(BackgroundProperty, new Binding("COLOR_HEX[" + cellNumber + "]")
                {
                    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                    NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                });
                lessonCell.SetBinding(LessonCell.SubjectNameProperty, new Binding("SUBJECT_NAME[" + cellNumber + "]")
                {
                    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                    NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                });
                lessonCell.SetBinding(LessonCell.TeacherNameProperty, new Binding("TEACHER_NAME[" + cellNumber + "]")
                {
                    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                    NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                });
                lessonCell.SetBinding(LessonCell.CabinetNameProperty, new Binding("CABINET_NAME[" + cellNumber + "]")
                {
                    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                    NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                });
                lessonColumn.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = lessonCell };
                ScheduleGrid.Columns.Add(lessonColumn);
                multiBindingWidth.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = lessonColumn });
```

The rows of the table are stored in ObservableCollection using my Custom Type ScheduleString

```
    private ObservableCollection<ScheduleString> ScheduleStringCollection = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleString>();

    public class ScheduleString
    {
        public int SCHEDVARIANT_ID { get; set; }

        public int CLASS_ID { get; set; }

        public string CLASS_NAME { get; set; }

        public int[] SCHEDSTRING_ID { get; set; }

        public int[] STUDTIME_ID { get; set; }

        public int[] LEARNCLASS_ID { get; set; }

        public int[] TEACHER_ID { get; set; }

        public string[] TEACHER_NAME { get; set; }

        public int[] SUBJECT_ID { get; set; }

        public string[] SUBJECT_NAME { get; set; }

        public int[] CABINET_ID { get; set; }

        public string[] CABINET_NAME { get; set; }

        public string[] COLOR_HEX { get; set; }
    }
```

Through Itemsource I assign this collection to a ScheduleGrid.
When I update the collection in my code the changes are loaded into the table, but not displayed in the my control. But if you double-click on the cell with the changed data Datagrid displays it. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `TemplateBindings` with ordinary bindings in your template:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SubjectName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:LessonCell}}"/>
```

`{TemplateBinding}` is an optimized version of a binding that comes with some limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. In ScheduleString class it is necessary to replace arrays on ObservableCollection

```
    public class ScheduleChange
    {
        public int SCHEDVARIANT_ID { get; set; }

        public int CLASS_ID { get; set; }

        public string CLASS_NAME { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<int> SCHEDCHANGE_ID { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<int> STUDTIME_ID { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<int> TEACHER_ID { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> TEACHER_NAME { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<int> SUBJECT_ID { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> SUBJECT_NAME { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<int> CABINET_ID { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> CABINET_NAME { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<int?> GROUP_ID { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<DateTime> CHANGE_DATE { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> COLOR_HEX { get; set; }
    }
```